# Can't mount NFS share with openvpn connection

Tags: mount, vpn, openvpn, nfs

I am having a weird issue at home with my Synology NAS and my home server which is an Intel NUC. Both of these devices are on the same LAN, and the NUC has a openvpn connection to a VPN provider with a public IPv4 address.

However the issue i'm having is i am unable to mount the NFS share that's from my Synology NAS. On my laptop, which is running Linux, i can mount it just fine.

The NUC is running Ubuntu Server on it.

I have tried the following:

- Disable UFW
- sudo mount 192.168.0.80:/volume1/Movies /mnt/synology on my NUC
- Tried follow various guides but since the laptop can connect just fine i don't think that its the NASs fault
- I have tried disabling openvpn.service on the nuc and rebooting it but the mount still wont work

I really need some help here, i don't know what is causing it to malfunction.